# What is the best way to encode parameters to pass it to other List / Page?

Tags: list, ddwrt, xslt

I would like to know the best way to encode parameters (with a space or other unsafe characters) when passing these to another List.

With **ddwrt:UrlEncode** ?

```
<xsl:variable name="MyURL"
  select="concat('../../Lists/MyList/MyView.aspx?MyID=',@ID,'&amp;MyName=',ddwrt:UrlEncode(string(@Title)))" />
```

The question is how to read this value on the page ?
This one fails :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$MyName" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that there's no need to encode a parameter using ddwrt:UrlEncode.

So the code on the **first** page becomes:

1) Building the URL

```
<xsl:variable name="MyURL" select="concat('../../Lists/MyList/MyView.aspx?ID=',@ID,'&amp;MyName=', @Title)" />
```

2) Creating a hyperlink

```
<a onclick="GoToLink(this); return false;" target="_self">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="$MyURL" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  Click My Link
</a>
```

Code on **second** page is just:

```
<ParameterBindings>
 ...
    <ParameterBinding Name="MyName" Location="QueryString(MyName)" DefaultValue="-"/>
</ParameterBindings>

<xsl:stylesheet />
  <xsl:param name="MyName" />
...

MyName : '<xsl:value-of select="$MyName" />'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely need to `URLEncode` values passed in URLs somehow. In plain .Net code this is done using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`, but if the ddwrt namespace has an XSL function which does this (as you appear to have found), I would have thought that should be fine too.

Can you verify this function works, perhaps by calling it in a different context?

Comment: oops, I see that some code was missing in my question, please take a look again.

The URLEncode function works correct.
MyView.aspx?MyID=',@ID,'&amp;MyName=',ddwrt:UrlEncode(string(@Title))
is correctly converted to
MyView.aspx?MyID=1&MyName=My+Long+Name+With+Spaces

But I guess that the + signs cannot be handled by
 <xsl:value-of select="$MyName" />
?

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't expect the '+' sign to cause a problem. However the thing that I'm wondering about the XSL you've provided is where is the 'MyName' XSL variable coming from? In what I see you just have a 'MyUrl' variable. 

I see that 'MyName' is a querystring parameter within the string which is in the 'MyUrl' variable, but I see no actual XSL variable called 'MyName' - this would explain the error. Does that make sense?

Comment: The URLEncode function is on the first page. And when a button is clicked, you are forwarded to the URL (second page). On that second page I've added a MyName Parameter and a MyName xslt variable, so that's not the problem. The problem is the + signs I think. Because normally you encode spaces with %20 ?

Comment: Spaces can be escaped with %20, or the issue avoided by replacing them with '+' which the function appears to do. I'm not sure I have the full picture of what you're trying to do, but as a suggestion for now, don't forget that whenever you URL encode something, you have to URL decode it on the receiving page. Do you have that somewhere?

Comment: I do not decode it, because there is no ddwrt:UrlDecode function.
Maybe I'm gonna write a custom xsl replace function which replaces all unsafe characters.